# Perf on MIPS debug kernel, unable to enable frame_pointer

Tags: linux-kernel, mips, perf

I am trying to use perf tool for MIPS & facing some trouble in getting back-stacks.

How can I enable FRAME_POINTER for mips ? I have DEBUG_KERNEL enabled, but it looks like -fno-omit-frame-pointer is not applicable for MIPS arch in [kernel](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Main_Page).

[image]

Does it mean frame pointer based stack unwinding with perf can't be achieved for MIPS ?

I don't see mips toolchain complaining about -fno-omit-frame-pointer flag

**EDIT1**

I am able to record perf events. Sample output for perf report

[image]

Report wouldn't help much without the stack unwinding.

```
# ./perf --version
perf version 5.6.rc2.gd04712cd3bd7
# uname -a
Linux localhost 3.14.28-1.19 #1 SMP Mon Feb 17 16:48:44 IST 2020 mips GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT2**

Perf features detected

```
Auto-detecting system features:
...                         dwarf: [ on  ]
...            dwarf_getlocations: [ on  ]
...                         glibc: [ on  ]
...                          gtk2: [ OFF ]
...                      libaudit: [ on  ]
...                        libbfd: [ OFF ]
...                        libcap: [ OFF ]
...                        libelf: [ on  ]
...                       libnuma: [ OFF ]
...        numa_num_possible_cpus: [ OFF ]
...                       libperl: [ OFF ]
...                     libpython: [ OFF ]
...                     libcrypto: [ OFF ]
...                     libunwind: [ OFF ]
...            libdw-dwarf-unwind: [ on  ]
...                          zlib: [ on  ]
...                          lzma: [ on  ]
...                     get_cpuid: [ OFF ]
...                           bpf: [ OFF ]
...                        libaio: [ on  ]
...                       libzstd: [ OFF ]
...        disassembler-four-args: [ OFF ]
```

**EDIT3**

I see feature test for libunwind had failed

```
cat linux-5.6-rc2/tools/build/feature/test-libunwind.make.output
/tmp/ccQnV5jZ.o: In function `main':
test-libunwind.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_Umips_create_addr_space'
test-libunwind.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `_Umips_init_remote'
test-libunwind.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `_Umips_dwarf_search_unwind_table'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I see the [makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/build/feature/Makefile#L164) for feature tests libunwind linking is not done for MIPS.

**EDIT4**

Usual workflow

```
perf record -F 99 -ag -e cycles:u -- sleep 5
perf report
```

Attempt to use dwarf

```
# perf record -F 99 -ag --call-graph=dwarf -- sleep 10                                                                                                                                                   
Error:
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 89 (Function not implemented) for event (cycles).
/bin/dmesg | grep -i perf may provide additional information.
```

dmesg is empty

Comment: What is your kernel version and what do you want to profile? Could you get some `perf record -g` runs and decode their `perf.data` output with `perf script` command. Post several events from the middle of `perf script` output and also post here warnings printed by `perf` commands

Comment: As I am running on embedded target I have not linked perf with python / perl libs, so scripting isn't available. Rest I have updated as edit.

Comment: `perf script` command can work without py/perl libs. It will just parse the perf.data and dump it as text. I have perf built from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/v5.5.0/ with `libperl: [ OFF ]` and `libpython: [ OFF ]` and my `./perf script` prints events (and `perf script -D` also shows hex dump or raw events). Never used perf script to run any script, only for parsing perf.data to text. What were your perf record and perf report commands (with full options)? Can you try different --call-graph options for record (x86 has fp, dwarf or lbr)?

Comment: perf script output is available here https://pastebin.com/furgUtLr, this is with default --call-graph fp.